# OpenGL ES: mixing perspective and orthographic projections

Tags: matrix, shader, opengl-es-2.0

I have a scene rendered using a perspective projection. I'm attempting to render an additional piece of geometry (a polyline) into the scene using an orthographic projection.

This is working fine, but the geometry rendered using the orthographic projection is always rendered above everything else in the scene. Ideally, I would like the polyline geometry to correctly maintain it's depth in terms of the depth buffer (with objects at a closer Z to the camera drawn over the top of it).

Is this possible, or would I be better off using a perspective projection for the polyline and negating things like perspective divide in the vertex shader?

Comment: Depths calculated in perspective are NOT related to those calculated in orthographic. Laters are Z-linear while formers are 1/Z - linear. Can you explain what you pretend mixing projections?

Comment: Can you provide a [mcve]?